# Trying to find distinct number of items in several co-related columns

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a table with 3 columns namely- Business function, Hosts and It Services. A business function owns multiple hosts and each host has multiple services associated with it.

An example of the table is as follows -

| Business Function | Host Name | It Services |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Commercial Banking | GigaTux | AAA |
| Commercial Banking | GigaTux | CCC |
| Wealth | HTX | RRR |
| Wealth | HTX | DDD |
| Commercial Banking | KDP | AAA |
| Wealth | Fusion | FFF |
| Commercial Banking | CreateX | QQQ |
| Wealth | Icon | ZZZ |

I need to find the number of distinct hosts within a business function and the number of shared hosts which have more than 1 IT services mapped to it within the distinct hosts of that business function.

The desired table is as follows (The name of the table is es_dashboard) -

| Business Function | Host | Shared Hosts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Commercial Banking | 3 | 1 |
| Wealth | 3 | 1 |

This is because Commercial banking has 3 distinct hosts- GigaTux, KDP and CreateX, and there's only 1 host (GigaTux) which has more than 1 IT Service mapped to it. Same thing applies to Wealth as well.

My current SQL code is as follows-

```
SELECT ES.business_function AS 'Business Function' , COUNT(DISTINCT host) AS 'Host ', 
    (SELECT count(*)
        FROM es_dashboard ESO     
        WHERE ES.business_function = ESO.business_function 
        AND ESO.host IN
            (SELECT EST.host
            FROM es_dashboard EST
            WHERE ES.business_function = EST.business_function AND EST.host = ESO.host AND count(distinct EST.it_service) > 2)
    ) AS "Shared Hosts"
FROM es_dashboard ES
GROUP BY BF;
```

The goal is to use a nested query without creating any new tables.

I can get the distinct hosts within a business function but having trouble in finding out the distinct IT services. Can someone help?

Comment: Which database system do you **really** use?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm using MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `sub-queries` to achieve this:

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    hst.Business_Function, 
    hst.HOST, 
    COALESCE (shr.SHARED_HOST,0) AS SHARED_HOST
FROM 
   (
    SELECT 
       Business_Function,
       COUNT(distinct Host_Name) as HOST
    FROM es_dashboard
    GROUP BY Business_Function
    ) AS hst

LEFT JOIN
   (
    SELECT Business_Function, 
          COUNT(DISTINCT HOST_Name) AS SHARED_HOST
    FROM
        (
         SELECT Business_Function, Host_Name, 
                COUNT(distinct It_services) AS it_cnt
         FROM es_dashboard AS esd
         GROUP BY Business_Function, Host_Name
        ) AS it
    WHERE it_cnt>1
    GROUP BY Business_Function
) AS shr
ON hst.Business_function = shr.business_function
```

**Query explanation:**

1. The sub-query in `FROM` clause will give us the count of HOSTS in each business function
2. The one in `JOIN` clause will give us the count of HOSTS with more than 1 `it_services`
3. Then we `LEFT JOIN` because there might be a chance that `NONE` of the hosts in a business function have >1 it_services
4. Using `COALESCE` to handle such cases (modify as per your requirement)

See DEMO [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=bf0f330a8ea76e023dfd294f0a46e8de)